# Xamarin.Forms IOS Breakpoints Not Hit

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, breakpoints

I recently upgraded to the new Xamarin for Visual Studio, and since then, I can no longer hit breakpoints during IOS debugging.  Android works fine, strangely.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 and left all of the defaults intact.  Previously, this has resolved odd issues like this one.

I have read dozens of similar complaints, but those solutions have not worked for me.

Comment: Are the breakpoints white or red? Have you tried already removing all the `bin` and `obj` folders from all projects and rebuilding? You could also try to locatie the cache folders on your Mac and clear those out.

Comment: I have done all your suggestions and STILL nothing works

Comment: I have been having the same problem. I am developing on VS 2017 Enterprise on windows 10, building on a mac and debugging on iPad connected to the mac via USB. I managed to get it to hit break points by going to properties of iOS project and on Build Settings setting Linker Behaviour to Dont Link and un select Strip Native debugging symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this did not work

Comment: What does "if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)" return for you? Try also System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); does it break on the line?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows and latest Xamarin using the iOS simulator on remote Mac. Debugging started, but breakpoints were not hit.

Got it working by changing **nothing** on the Mac or iOS Build options; instead changed the generated **Debugging information** type in Visual Studio 2017 in Windows from "Full" or "Pdb-only" to **"Portable"**.

[image: Debugging information setting in Visual Studio 2017 Project properties]

I did this for the iOS Platform project as well as the shared Xamarin.Forms project (.NET Standard 2.0).

After this the breakpoints started getting hit in both the Shared project and the iOS platform project. Good times.

Comment: I was in the middle of working on the same project I work on every day and all of a sudden my iOS breakpoints stopped working this morning. Tried everything until I saw this and tried it and it fixed my issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to disable linking in the iOS project (not PCL project). This worked for me.

> 1. Go to iOS project settings
> 2. iOS Build
> 3. Linker Behavior: Don't Link.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `Xamarin.iOS`, which will is fixed in `Xamarin.iOS 10.12.0.12 (494fcbc)`, which should be available in beta channel. The problem seems only to occur in a PCL, which is the case if you set a breakpoint in your portable project (Xamarin.Forms code).

There is a temporary [workaround](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56893#c2), which worked for me:

> Possible temporary workaround: switch the portable class library
>   project(s) to output "portable" PDB files rather than "full" PDB files
>
> 1. Open the portable class library .csproj file in a text editor.  For example, right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select
>      Unload Project, and then right-click it again and select "Edit ...".
> 2. Under the PropertyGroup for the "Debug|AnyCPU" configuration, change the DebugType to: portable
> 3. Save the change and reload the project.
> 4. Build, deploy, and start debugging the iOS app project again.

There is an issue on Android if you do the above steps. To be able to hit the breakpoints on Android again, you have to do [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56893#c7):

> Long story short, if you manually delete the "bin" and "obj" folders
>   for each of the projects that you have switched to `portable`,
>   uninstall the app from the test device, and then clean and rebuild the
>   solution, that should hopefully allow the `portable` mode to work with
>   Android too.  Once you have performed those clean-up steps once, you
>   should in theory not need to perform them again unless you switch the
>   DebugType again.

**Edit**

On Android I still have [troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45632836/426227), so it's not the perfect way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Visual Studio for Mac, Solution explorer and choose the project,
Project->Option->Compiler->Debug information,  choose “Full” in dropdown.

You need set this "Full" for EACH of those projects in the solution you want to debug otherwise the breakpoint will not kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms: Make sure that your view is bound with the binding context otherwise breakpoints will not hit.  And the breakpoints appear as symbols not loaded.

Example :

```
public ExamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = App.Resolve<ExampleViewModel>();
    }
```

That resolved the issue for me:)

Answer (score -2):

After doing lotsof digging finally got the solution, kindly look in the attached screen short.

In VS 2019 Community edition.

[image]