# Cannot Hit Breakpoints in PCL when Running iOS Project

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Hello I have been trying to debug an iOS project that was built with Xamarin Forms but have been unable to hit a single breakpoint in the Portable Class Library.

When I debug I run the program on an actual device that is connected to my Mac OS X. However the code lives in a Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise editor which is running in parallels Windows 10. Many others have had the same issue but with no solution like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015510/xamarin-forms-ios-breakpoints-not-hit#comment76646604_44015510)

Here is a list of everything I have tried thus far:

- Deleting the bin and obj folders then clean and rebuild
- Setting the iOS build property "Link Behavior" to "Don't Link"
- Unselecting Strip native debugging symbols
- Removed all symbols on path to debug file
- Enabling Debugging in iOS build properties
- Running in VS Professional and Enterprise
- Deleting the.suo file in the vs directory
- Adding `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>` to .shproj
- Daniel Sgorbini's suggestion [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41714/breakpoints-not-hitting) though no method in my after.targets file called convert debugging files

If you have any other suggestions for other things that may work I am all ears. Thank You!

Comment: this is a real showstopper for me...  did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: yes. I will post my answer tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Xamarin iOS 10.10. Release 10.12 solved the issue which required installing Visual Studio Preview.

For instructions on how to install a beta release of Xamarin [check this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110554/update-to-xamarin-ios-10-12-in-visual-studio-2017).

FYI I have since upgraded to Xamarin iOS 10.99 and have not had this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

We have to DownGrade Mono5.0 to 4.8.1 then it will work,

Fellow below link

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/281049#Comment_281049

After downgrading

Close VisualStudio, Now clean & rebuild the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

Project Options -> Build -> compiler -> Debug information: "Symbols only"

Hope this helps for you.

Thanks

[image]