# Update to Xamarin iOS 10.12 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I would like to get this version of Xamarin installed on my machine.

Unfortunately after downloading the Xamarin Updater (nothing appears in updates in the Extensions and Updates window for Xamarin) and uninstalling and reinstalling Xamarin in Visual Studio I still have version 10.10.

There is a bug fix in 10.12 release that I desperately need for my project.

**How do I update from 10.10 to 10.12 in Visual Studio 2017?**

Comment: Are you on the beta channel? `Xamarin.iOS` `10.12.0.14` is in the *Beta Channel* : https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-release-15-3-preview-4/

Comment: No I am not! How do I switch to the beta channel in VS?

Comment: I have visited that page many times but I am unable to download the release

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/

Comment: You should have another program installed alongside of Visual Studio 2017 called "Visual Studio Installer" which you can install updates from.

Comment: @RyeGuy updated my answer to include a link to the preview installer for visual studio 2017, you essentially install a second instance of VS 2017 that's marked as 'preview' and it will get all of the pre-release updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xamarin Updater to update to Beta release of Xamarin. In order to do that, you will need to update your Visual Studio to 15.3 preview version first. Then you can follow the steps in [this blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/staying-date-visual-studio-2017-xamarin-updater/) to install the Xamarin Updater in Visual Studio 2017. After that, you will have the same updater like you previously have in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I know this was answered a while age. However is there anywhere in Visual Studio 2017 where I have to explicitly alter the update channel to download the beta version of Xamarin? Or does it offer the beta automatically? This link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/ does not give any indication you do or not

Comment: Reason I ask is that I am trying to install Xamarin iOS 10.99 but the Xamarin updater is not detecting any updates

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2017 does not have the updater to switch channel to Beta/Alpha like in Visual Studio 2015. It only have Release and Preview. So it is up to Xamarin team whether they release the version into Preview version in VS2017.

Comment: It seems that the Xamarin Updater is no longer available. Is there an other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation from Xamarin found [HERE.](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/)

> To try out pre-release features, you should download the Visual Studio
>   2017 Preview installer, which will offer the option to install Preview
>   versions of Visual Studio side-by-side (SxS) with the stable (Release)
>   version. More information is available in the Visual Studio 2017
>   Preview FAQ.

So from the looks of it they've switched to 'stable' and 'preview' streams in 2017, and that relates specifically to the VS instance you run. Hit up the link and follow the instructions and you should be golden.

**EDIT:** Keeping this here just incase (VS 2015 edition)

In visual studio you simply go to tools > options > then you will see a 'xamarin' tab on the left of the options pane.

[image: visual studio options pane]

under each platform (android, and iOS) theres a drop down to switch between 'stable' and 'beta' channels, once you've switched you can force it to check for updates and if there is one available it will prompt you to download and install it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not how updates work in VS 2017. This is only for VS 2015.